# Passing id of image to function and display count

Tags: javascript, html

I have a static page with the following markup

```
 <div class="middle-content">
    <div class="white-div">
        <div class="like-buttons">
            <img id="1" src="up.png" onclick="onClick(true, this.id)" />
            <span id="clickOne">0</span>
            <img id="2" src="down.png" onclick="onClick(false, this.id)" />
        </div>
        <div class="tex-area">
            <h4>Heading One</h4>
            <p>Some random paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="red-div">
        <div class="like-buttons">
            <img id="3" src="up.png" onclick="onClick(true, this.id)" />
            <span id="clickTwo">0</span>
            <img id="4" src="down.png" onclick="onClick(false, this.id)" />
        </div>
        <div class="tex-area">
            <h4>Heading Two</h4>
            <p>Some random paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="white-div">
        <div class="like-buttons">
            <img id="5" src="up.png" onclick="onClick(true, this.id)" />
            <span id="clickThree">0</span>
            <img id="6" src="down.png" onclick="onClick(false, this.id)" />
        </div>
        <div class="tex-area">
            <h4>Heading Three</h4>
            <p>Some random paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="red-div">
        <div class="like-buttons">
            <img id="7" src="up.png" onclick="onClick(true, this.id)" />
            <span id="clickFour">0</span>
            <img id="8" src="down.png" onclick="onClick(false, this.id)" />
        </div>
        <div class="tex-area">
            <h4>Heading Four</h4>
            <p>Some random paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript function is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;
    function onClick(flag, id) {
        alert(id); //Displays empty 
        if (flag && clicks < 10)
            clicks += 1;
        else if (!flag && clicks > 0)
            clicks -= 1;
        document.getElementById("clickOne").innerHTML = clicks;
        //How to ensure only relevant count goes up depending on the image clicked?
    };
</script>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when a user clicks on one of the images only that span count for the particular section goes up and no other one. I've tried passing the id through but the `alert` comes back as blank. Can someone suggest where I'm going wrong or what would be the correct way to approach this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: clearly `"onClick(true, this.id)"` isn't working - why not replace `this.id` with the `id` of the image? or better yet, pass the id of the span that holds the value (clickOne, clickTwo, clickThree etc)

Comment: try to rename your ids to start with some letter instead of number

Comment: @KamenStoykov Unless he's using a really old browser, that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ayqths0a/)!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak That's weird because the exact code on my dev side doesn't work but the fiddle you provided is working :/

Comment: Can you provide a link to the dev site?

Comment: @Code Check browser console for errors.

Comment: @Code you should accept DhavalMarthak's Answer. You have missed something in your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="red-div">
    <div class="like-buttons">
        <img id="3" src="up.png" onclick="onClick(true, 'clickTwo')" />
        <span id="clickTwo">0</span>
        <img id="4" src="down.png" onclick="onClick(false, 'clickTwo')" />
    </div>
    <div class="tex-area">
        <h4>Heading Two</h4>
        <p>Some random paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>


function onClick(flag, id) {
    var clicks = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).textContent, 10);
    if (flag && clicks < 10)
        clicks += 1;
    else if (!flag && clicks > 0)
        clicks -= 1;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

Here's a solution that doesn't need ID's at all

```
<div class="white-div">
    <div class="like-buttons">
        <img src="up.png" onclick="onClick(true, this)" />
        <span>0</span>
        <img src="down.png" onclick="onClick(false, this)" />
    </div>
    <div class="tex-area">
        <h4>Heading One</h4>
        <p>Some random paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript

```
function onClick(flag, el) {
    var span = el.parentElement.querySelector('span');
    var clicks = parseInt(span.textContent, 10);
    if (flag && clicks < 10)
        clicks += 1;
    else if (!flag && clicks > 0)
        clicks -= 1;
    span.innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

Here it is working - http://jsfiddle.net/d1bd3eut/1/

I'm on a roll ...

```
<div class="white-div">
    <div class="like-buttons">
        <img src="up.png" onclick="onClick(this)" />
        <span>0</span>
        <img src="down.png" onclick="onClick(this)" />
    </div>
    <div class="tex-area">
        <h4>Heading One</h4>
        <p>Some random paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function onClick(el) {
    var span = el.parentElement.querySelector('span');
    var clicks = parseInt(span.textContent, 10);
    var value = -Math.sign(el.src.indexOf('own.png'));
    clicks = Math.max(0, Math.min(clicks + value, 10));
    span.innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d1bd3eut/3/

Comment: you want an even better solution? who needs id's at all :p

Comment: Wow! That's awesome.. Thank you ever so much